# Apache Camel 3.14.9 : Exception Handling inside processor with CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode

Tags: exception, apache-camel, jms

I have a router with Aggregator -> Splitter -> Resequencer EIP. When the resequencer batch send exchanges one by one to a processor I have to send rest of the messages to a different queue after I have a exception for an exchange. Is it possible?

Any sample code block will be a great help here.

I am using Spring Boot with Apache Camel and the Java DSL.

//edited after Julian's comment

1. CLIENT_ACKNOWLEGEMENT is required, because it might happen that Route could crash during processing for Aggregated Batch.
2. Could you please explain "the whole lot" vs "just the aggregated batch".
3. Here is the router implementation

   `from("inputQueue?concurrentConsumers=5&acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE")     //CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE set
   .routeId("Consumer")

   .aggregate(header("AGG_ID"), new AggregationStrategy(){ // 1.Aggregating
   @Override
   public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {

   oldExchange.getIn().setBody(oldBody + SEPARATOR + newBody);

   return oldExchange;
   }
   })
   .completionTimeout(5000L)
   .completionSize(5)      //2. Aggregate for 5 messages or wait till 5 seconds
   .split(simple("${body}")).delimiter("|~~|").parallelProcessing(false) // 3. Splitting

   .resequence(xpath("//*[local-name()='TimeStamp']")) // 4. resequencing based on TimeStamp in Message
   .batch(new BatchResequencerConfig(5, 5000L)).allowDuplicates() //5. Aggregate and resequence batch size are same
   .process(new Processor() {

   @Override
   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
   //processing logic :: external service call   // 6. Exception conneting to external system, I must reject others messages inside the current batch and
   //send send them to another queue.
   //There will be onExeption().handle(true) defined inside the router, so that client acknowledgement send and broker removed the message from queue.

   }
   })
   .to("outputQueue");`

   So the main intension is to stop processing of next messages for a batch of 5 messages, when there is an exception for any message. And if route crashes then all message must be available in the input queue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement well, you want your `resequencer` to direct exchanges to a certain `Processor` but if an exception happens you want the messages to be delivered to a different endpoint.

It is hard to give you a code example without knowing exactly what your requirements are. E.g. what is the definition of the `rest of the messages`? Are you referring to the whole lot or just the aggregated batch?

Anyway, the approach to solve this problem is the same but would have different flavors depending on your exact needs. You can implement a singleton storing the path to go which normally would be `direct:default` but when something bad happens switch the path to `direct:error`. And at the exit of `resequencer` you have a processor which will route the messages based on the current path stored in singleton. Enums are a good singleton implementation so here is one approach:

```
public Enum Destination {
    PATH;

    @Getter
    private String value = "direct:default";

    public void switchToError() {
       value = "direct:error"; 
    }
    
    public void switchToDefault() {
        value = "direct:default";
    }
}
```

So, in your main route you will have something like this:

```
resequence(body()).batch()
.process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setHeader("next", Destination.PATH.getValue()))
.routingSlip(header("next"));
```

And you set the path to `direct:error` in your error handling section:

```
onException(Exception.class)
.process(exchange -> Destination.PATH.switchToError())
.handled(true)
.to("direct:error");
```

And of course you can `swithToDefault` when a new aggregate completes.

Hope it helps even I was not clear at all what `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` means from your problem description.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I will try your suggestions and get back to you.

Comment: Hello Julian, Thank you for your suggestion. Let me explain the situation in more details. I have updated my question with sample route, and commented

Comment: Yes so my suggestion will work perfectly. All you need is to catch the exception in your processor (the one calling the external system) and set the `Destination.PATH` to "direct:error" then after your processor insert my piece of code provided in the `routingSplit` section. Then you implement `from("direct:error")` and `from("direct:default")` sub-routes as well as reseting the `Destination.PATH` when the aggregation completes